Remove contours of filled areas
I think this was already asked but not answered before, but I cannot find the post. Consider a plot with filling:
gr = Plot[x^2, {x, -1, 1}, Filling -> Bottom, 
  PlotTheme -> {"Frame", "PastelColor"}, 
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.001], 
  FillingStyle -> {Thickness[0.0], Opacity[0.2]}]
Export["a.pdf", gr]

The goal is to have a single curve, and area under the curve filled. Only these two elements. However, MA produces more as this magnification shows

There is a halo line around the filled area. The question is how to get rid of it. I need this for very small plots where these lines are quite distracting. Notice, that exporting in PNG format seems to work as intended.

This bug have been fixed before version 13.3.

@cvgmt My version is 13.1. Was it fixed in 13.2 then?

13.3.1 work fine,just as 14.0. I don't have version  13.2.
